# File ended while scanning use of \url using Bibtex.

Tags: bibtex, urls

I have a problem with one of my bibtex items and I'm scratching my head to figure out what is wrong. I've narrowed it down to the specific reference, and in partiuclar the specific URL latex is having trouble compiling. It is the following:

```
    url = {http://www.opengroup.org/jericho/Jericho%20Forum%20Identity%20Commandments%20v1.0.pdf},
```

Usually this error occurs due to unbalanced paranthesis, but that is not the case here. What is problematic about this particular URL?

Answer (score 13):

Load the [url](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package in the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{url}
```

Comment: This works, but it changes the formatting of URLs in the bibliography, which isn't necessarily wanted.

Comment: @naught101 usually URLs are typeset in monospaced font. To change the font with the package loaded,  use `\urlstyle{same}` or some other of the available options.

Answer (score 4):

Is it that % is the Tex comment character? Try putting backslashes before each %

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I recently encountered a similar problem. After fixing errors in the .bib document (such as adding backslashes to the %) remember to delete the .bbl document first and recompile.

The way I add urls to bibtex is thus:

```
@misc{fenwayHouse,
  title={{Fenway House}},
  howpublished="\url{http://web.mit.edu/fenwayhouse}"
}
```

Made a stupid mistake by doing

`howpublished="\url={http://web.mit.edu/fenwayhouse}"`

instead (notice the extra misplaced `=`).

After finding that out and simply recompiling, I was scratching my head that the error still existed.

So this is an obvious fix that I neglected to notice, delete the .bbl file which is generated the first time you reference something in the .bib, this does not "update" fully when you change your an entry in .bib that has already been carried over to .bbl, so that extra `=` was still causing errors.

Comment: Well, this might be a solution. Could a please elaborate a little more on this, perhaps with some example?